# How to convert fixed point (Q format) number to floating point in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Why [int16](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int16.html) doesn't retrieve the sign from an hex string?

**MATLAB:**

```
>> single(int16(hex2dec('ffff')))
ans =

       32767
```

i.e.

```
>> int16(hex2dec('ffff')) == int16(hex2dec('8fff'))

ans =

     1
```

To put it in its general context, I want to rewrite the following numpy **Python** snippet code in MATLAB:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> i='ffff'
>>> q='3fff'
>>> i_float = np.int16(int(i,16))
>>> i_float = i_float * 2 ** -15
>>> i_float
-3.0517578125e-05
>>> q_float = np.int16(int(q,16))
>>> q_float = q_float * 2 ** -15
>>> q_float
0.499969482421875
```

Comment: I think you're confused. hex2dec('ffff')=65535 and hex2dec('8fff')=36863. So this has nothing to do with signs.

Comment: The python code snippet you show doesn't handle negative hex either. `int(i, 16)` interprets it as hex without signs.

Comment: `int16(int('ffff',16))` gives me -1 in python 2.7.  I don't understand what you mean.  Is `hex2dec` standard python?  In what module?

Comment: The question is why `int16(int('ffff',16))` gives `-1` in python and in Matlab `int16(hex2dec('ffff'))` gives `1`.

Comment: MATLAB doesn't give `1`, as per the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int16.html) `hex2dec('ffff') = 65535` and `int16(65535)` truncates that to `32767`.  In numpy on the other hand there is no bounds checking and `np.int16` wraps rather than truncates.

Comment: @PhilGoddard, so how do you suggest to convert fixed point 1.15 representation to a floating point?

Comment: What's the fixed point representation?  Nominally in MATLAB I'd just do `double(1.15)`.

Comment: Are you sure you know what I am talking about? [Q format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format))

Comment: I know a lot about fixed point numbers, but your original question is about converting a hex number represented as a string, and now you're asking about converting fixed point 1.15 (which may use a limited number of bits in memory, i.e. be a fixed point representation, but is still a number) into a floating point number.

Comment: @PhilGoddard what I am trying to achieve is that given fixed point samples in hex format how to convert it to floating point

Comment: Do you have access to the Fixed Point Designer Toolbox?  It has various functions for doing this type of conversion.

Comment: @PhilGoddard, thanks for the tip. I couldn't find a function that takes a number in fixed point such as 0xFFFF and convert it into double in the [API](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/fixed-point-data-representation.html)

Comment: Just to be clear (I'm not very familiar with Q format), you want the positive value, right? So why not use `uint16` instead of `int16`?

Comment: @beaker I want the signed value....

Comment: Ah, okay. Yeah, the conversion from hex to decimal only handles positive values. If you can provide an example of the expected output I'll try to put something together.

Comment: @beaker, please refer to the Python snippet I have just put in my question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've got. (Yes, it seems to be more convoluted than it should be.)

```
i_hex = 'ffff'
q_hex = '3fff'

i_int16 = typecast(uint16(hex2dec(i_hex)),'int16')
i_float = single(i_int16) * 2 ^ -15

q_int16 = typecast(uint16(hex2dec(q_hex)),'int16')
q_float = single(q_int16) * 2 ^ -15
```

Output:

```
i_hex = ffff
q_hex = 3fff
i_int16 = -1
i_float =   -3.05175781250000e-05
q_int16 = 16383
q_float =  0.499969482421875
```

`hex2dec` converts hex to a double, so I cast it to a `uint16` so as to preserve the sign bit (which `hex2dec` refuses to do). Then I `typecast` the result to a signed `int16`. This just takes the bits of the `uint16` and interprets them as an `int16`. Then cast it to a `single` and bitshift.

Note: I used `format long` to see as many decimal places as I could.